# Timezone in the url requested from an iOS app

Tags: ios, timezone, url-parameters

I'm trying to request data from a url of the form `www.myurl.com/a?timezone=+n.n` using `NSMutableURLRequest` in an iOS app. `+n.n` or `-n.n` refer to the timezone of the device from which is the request is made.

**How do I populate this timezone parameter in the url?**

I've searched around and didn't find anything related to timezones w/ the above format.

Comment: First you need to understand that that won't be an actual time zone. It's an offset from UTC, but that's not enough to determine the actual time zone. Several different time zones can have the same *current* offset from UTC, but different rules around when they *change* offset.

Comment: The dot is pretty odd. You usually either use a format like `+0200` or `+02:00`. And those two would be easy to solve.

Comment: @JonSkeet +1 Ok that makes sense. I used the term timezone because the sparse documentation I have refers to it like that.

Comment: Yup, unfortunately it's a common mistake in terminology :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to solve this in steps. First, let's get a string that will be almost what your want (beware, untested):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter;
NSString *almostThere;

formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormat:@"ZZZZZ" allowNaturalLanguage:NO];
almostThere = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
[formatter release];
```

Now `almostThere` should be something like `-08:00` according to the [date format string documentation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns) (NSDateFormatter uses the Unicode formatting and references this document).

So all that's left is now to replace the colon with a dot:

```
NSString *tz;

tz = [almostThere stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"."];
```

And finally, the URL:

```
NSURL *theURL;
NSString *urlString;

urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myurl.com/a?timezone=%@", tz]
theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! Only thing I had to do was call `init` on the date formatter and set the `dateFormat` property. Looks like `initWithDateFormat:allowNaturalLanguage:` is available only on OS X.